# Android checkbox checked one variable

Tags: java, android

I have a  many checkbox and I saved in a String if it's checked like this:

```
 String juice = "";

 if (apple.isChecked()) {
      juice = apple.getText().toString().trim() + " " + etiquetas;
 }
 if (orange.isChecked()) {
      juice = orange.getText().toString().trim() + " " + etiquetas;
 }
```

But when I need in another Activity put the checkbox checked, idk how to checked because I saved in one. **I really need to be like this in one variable, because they're instructions for the exam.** And thas's my code for the other Activity;

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent != null){
     String juice_2 = (String) getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_JUICE"); 
     //apple.setChecked();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug and see what's inside Intent? Do you see your intent being passed with the key value pair? Find out and isolate where the error is first, before sending the intent or after receiving the intent.

Comment: in my intent idk but it´s blank, it has nothing

Comment: You need to put extra in the sending intent like this - getIntent().putExtra("EXTRA_JUICE", juice)

Comment: Then that means your intent does not have any extra key value pair. Add the key value pair in your sender activity as shown by @saurabh1489.

Comment: but the variable juice i don't have in the other activity

Comment: is a string? because gives me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current activity, you can use a single String that has multiple **juice** words separated by a SPACE character.

And at the destination activity, split the string into an array of strings based on the SPACE character, and then set the `checkBox` value if this array contains your specific juice.

at Activity A:

```
String juice = "";

if (apple.isChecked()) {
    juice = apple.getText().toString().trim() + " ";
}
if (orange.isChecked()) {
    juice = orange.getText().toString().trim() + " ";
}

// Going to Activity B
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("JUICE", juice);
startActivity(intent);
```

at Activity B:

```
if (getIntent() != null) {
    String juice = getIntent().getStringExtra("JUICE");
    if (juice != null) {
        String[] splittedJuice = juice.split(" ");
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        // Convert array into a List
        Collections.addAll(list, oldLines);
        // Check if the list contains "orange"
        if (list1.contains("orange")) {
            orange.setChecked(true);
        }

        if (list1.contains("apple")) {
            apple.setChecked(true);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from one activity to another you can use `Intent.putExtra()`.
The line will look something like this:

```
intent.putExtra(LABEL, juice);
```

where: `LABEL`  is a String which allows second activity to find your variable,
`juice` is your variable.

To resolve the problem you can use something like this:

```
public class First extends AppCompatActivity {

private final static String LABEL = "juices";
String juice;
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first);

    final CheckBox apple = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.apple);
    Button nextIntent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);

    nextIntent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (apple.isChecked()) {
                juice = apple.getText().toString();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second.class);
            intent.putExtra(LABEL, juice);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Second Activity:

```
public class Second extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final static String LABEL = "juices";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String dataReceived = intent.getStringExtra(LABEL);
        System.out.println("Your string: " + dataReceived);

    }
}
```

Anyway, I would recommend that you pass Boolean values to the next activity without converting them to a String if it's only to check/uncheck Checkboxes in the second layout.

If you have a lot of variables in the first activity you can pass them to the array, send it to the another activity (by the similar way) and iterate to check/uncheck boxes.